# Visual Studio 17.4 update changed font

Tags: visual-studio, settings

The update for Visual Studio 17.4 has changed the font in the text editor, so that it is very thin and a bit of a strain on the eyes to the read.  How can you change this back, short of rolling back the update?

Please note that I've searched a little bit for this, and I see the following setting:

[image]

But I have no idea what to set this to.  People have mentioned the Consolas font on one or more other posts, but that doesn't seem to match what was there before.  I've tried checking `Bold`.  Etc.

I just need it back to the "normal Visual Studio font" that was there before the update to 17.4, which has enough thickness in the letters that it's not uncomfortable to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there was a bug in the installer that incorrecly uninstalled the fonts during update ([17.4.4 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.4.4))

> "Addressed an issue when Cascadia Code and Cascadia Mono font gets
> uninstalled during Visual Studio update process."

It is [said to be fixed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cascadia-Mono-is-missing-and-VS-uses-cou/1679085) in 17.4.4
with the note that updating from previous version to 17.4.4 may experience the issue, but that it will not happen with future updates (e.g. 17.4.4 -> 17.4.5.)

Comment: Thank you.  This update wound up fixing it on my side.

Answer (score 3):

Happened to me too, and let me say that the "new" font is pretty ugly compared to the [original one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) that was `Cascadia Mono SemiBold`. Also uncheck `bold` if was checked and the size should be to `10`.
(Sadly, in my case, it is no more present in the fonts list. Maybe this is the reason why it was set back to default. But `Cascadia Code SemiBold` should be 99,9% similar)

In this case, you can download [Cascadia Mono Releases](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases) and install it again (?) in your system.

Answer (score 2):

I also had issues with the font, installing other fonts didn't help. I installed the [Text Sharp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.TextSharp) addon and enabled ClearType rendering which seemed to fix the font trouble I was having.

[image]

Edit: After more investigation, Visual studio has settings for text rendering thus disabling the addon and setting the Text rendering method to ClearType gives me back the original font:

[image]

And it seems like changing the Text Formatting method to Display instead of Ideal gives me the original issue I had.

And I also had to download [Cascadia Mono](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code) to get the Cascadia Code font but without the ligatures (i.e. not changing != to an = with a line through it)